# Static constructor gives syntax error in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, static

I've been looking at this error for a long time and I just cannot wrap my head around it.

Here's the code:

```js
class Instance {

    static {

    }

}

module.exports = Instance;
```

That is all there is. The class was full of stuff but I deleted them all because they are irrevelant. It's giving the same error with or without them.

The error:

```
    static {
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path\to\project\index.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

I've used static constructors in the past and testing the same code somewhere else seems to work so I dont understand what the issue is here. Please help me.

**SOLUTION**: Updated Node to 16.13.1 and it now works. 16.7.0 wasnt enough.

Comment: I’m not sure static constructors exist in JS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156270/static-constructor-in-javascript-es6

Comment: The constructor is a property of the prototype object, you can't use "static" constructor.

Comment: What version of Node? Static blocks are 16+.

Comment: I am talking about the initialization block https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_static_initialization_blocks

Edit: node version is 16.7.0

Comment: It seems to be a ES2022 feature. I can’t find evidence that it’s been implemented in node yet (although I’m likely wrong)

Comment: Just realized, this is the first time I'm using it on Node. All of the times before I've used them on plain JS on the browser. I dont see how it makes a difference though. I will try to update my node and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It makes a difference because JS changes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supported by Node 17.3.0. It is an ES2022 feature. This https://node.green/#ES2022 is a nice link to find ES feature compatibility in Nodejs. You will have to download the current version of Nodejs which is 17.3.0.
[image]

Comment: This is the answer. However just updating to 16.13.1 fixed the issue for me.